# The argument type 'Player Function(Player)' can't be assigned to parameter type 'Player Function(User)'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am trying to migrate my flutter project over to the newest version of Firebase and when I used the newest dependency it is now telling me that there is some conflict between User from firebase and Player from my own Player class. Thanks!

```
import 'package:final_firebase_test/models/player.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';



class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Player _userFromFirebaseUser(Player player) {
    return player != null ? Player(uid: player.uid) : null;
  }

  // Auth change user stream
  Stream<Player> get player {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(
            (Player player) => _userFromFirebaseUser(player) //This is where it is giving me the error
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because

```dart
_auth.authStateChanges()
```

returns a `Stream<User>`. To fix it, just change your `player` property to

```
Stream<Player> get player {
  return _auth.authStateChanges().map((user) => _userFromFirebaseUser(user));
}
```

and your `_userFromFirebaseUser` to

```dart
Player _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
  return user != null ? Player(uid: user.uid) : null;
}
```